# Azure Logic Apps - Show text/plain instead of XML

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App Request/Response that is querying a SQL DB and giving a response of:

```
{
    "Table1": [{
        "IP": "123"
    }, {
        "IP": "12345678"
    }, {
        "IP": "7777"
    }, {
        "IP": "999999"
    }]
}
```

But I would like instead a flat text file like:

```
123
12345678
7777
999999
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve that adding an Azure Function that will extract the information you need and call it from your Logic App:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Table1
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
}

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{        
log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

// Get request body
dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data.ToString());

    var ips = new List<string>(); 

    foreach(var table1 in root.Table1)
        ips.Add(table1.IP);

    var output = string.Join("\n", ips);

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, output);

}
```

Comment: Nice!  Would you be able to write this possibly?  I'm a bit of a newbie.  Or should I post a new question for that?